# Filter.jar in java project

Tags: java, xliff

I want to ask about xliff filters.jar file.
XLIFF (XML Localisation Interchange File Format) is an XML-based format created to standardize the way localizable data are passed between tools during a localization process.

my project is about localization.

Translating sentences from source to destination language.i want to use filters.
jar so that i can take an input in any file format and translation will be done and then i get the output as it is.

So i want to know how to use that filters.jar file in my existing project.
how to import the this jar file in eclipse project ?
thank u

Answer (score 0):

if you work eclipse read this [page](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Without Eclipse :

javac -classpath external.jar myClass.java
EDIT:

If your main class is in a package

```
package com.mycompany;
public class myClass
{
...
...
then
```

you'll need

```
javac -classpath external.jar com/mycompany/myClass.java
```

and

to run

```
java -classpath external.jar com.mycompany.myClass
```